# Why is array still empty?

Tags: swift

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

var posts = [Post]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchPosts()
}
    
func fetchPosts() {

    let userDBRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    
    userDBRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        guard let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        userDict.forEach { key, value in
            let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: value as! [String : Any])

            postRef.child(user.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                guard let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                postDict.forEach { key, value in
                    let post = Post(user: user, dictionary: value as! [String: Any])
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(posts)
   }
 }
```

Hi! here is my code. I'm trying to fetch post data from firebase, but even I appended every single post to posts, posts is still empty when I print it. I know It works in snapshot block. I wanna use posts outside of foreach or snapshot block. Thank you!

Comment: You're appending to `self.posts`, not `posts`.

Comment: Did you check if any returns are getting triggered for any guard let?

Comment: your `print` is in the wrong place. It is outside the closure. Put it just after `postDict.forEach {...}`

Comment: You have nested `asynchronous` functions, so in this case 
  I suggest you look-up asynchronous functions, completion handlers and `DispatchGroup`.
  Or better still, look-up async/await concurrency with `withTaskGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your array is empty, is because you are dealing with `asynchronous functions`.
You have to `wait` until all those `asynchronous functions` have finished
before you can access the results.

You could try the following approach (untested) using `DispatchGroup`, to "wait" for the results
before returning them.

You will have to adjust the code for your needs. Ensure that whenever you have
a `dispatch.enter()` you have the corresponding `dispatch.leave()`.

```
func fetchPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {

    let userDBRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

    var results = [Post]()  // <-- here
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()  // <-- here

    dispatch.enter()  // <-- A
    userDBRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        guard let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            dispatch.leave() // <-- A
            return
        }

        userDict.forEach { key, value in
            let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: value as! [String : Any])
            dispatch.enter()  // <-- B
            postRef.child(user.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                guard let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    dispatch.leave() // <-- B
                    return
                }
                postDict.forEach { key, value in
                    let post = Post(user: user, dictionary: value as! [String: Any])
                    results.append(post)
                }
                dispatch.leave() // <-- B
            }
        }
        
        dispatch.leave() // <-- A
    }

    dispatch.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(results)
    }

}
```

Use it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchPosts() { results in  // <-- here
        posts = results
        print("---> posts: \(posts)")
    }
}
```